# Creating a field in a Firestore collection from a field referenced in another Firestore collection using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a field ("artistName") in a Firestore collection ("shows") that is pulling from a field ("name") in another Firestore collection ("artists"). The "shows" collection has a reference field ("artist") that points to the a document in the "artists" collection. To create the field, Im using Google Cloud Functions. Here is my code:

```
exports.addReferenceDataToCollection = functions.firestore
  .document('shows/{showId}').onWrite(event => {
  var newValue = event.data.data();
  var artistId = newValue.artist.id;
  var artistRef = firestore.collection('artists').doc(artistId);

  return event.data.ref.set({
    artistName: artistRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
      } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        var artistName = doc.data().name;
        console.log('Artist Name:', artistName);
        return Promise.resolve(artistName);
      }
    })
  }, {merge: true});
});
```

I cant seem to get the data out of the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `artistRef.get()` first, then after you have the document you need, use its data in `event.data.ref.set()`.  As you've written it now, you're assigning a promise object to the `artistName` property.

The general form of this type of pattern looks like this:

```
// First get the artist doc
return artistRef.get().then(doc => {
    return event.data.ref.set({
        // use the properties of the doc in here
    })
})
```